# Is there an SQL wrapper to query an HTML table

Tags: java, c++, sql, html-parsing

There are lots of questions on how to format the results of an SQL query to an HTML table, but I'd like to go the other way - given an arbitrary HTML table with a header row, I'd like to be able to extract information form one or more rows using SQL (or an SQL-like language). Simple to state, but apparently not so simple to accomplish.

Ultimately, I'd prefer to parse the HTML properly with something like libtidy or JSoup, but while the API documentation is usually reasonable, when it comes to examples or tutorials on actually *using* them, you usually find an example of extracting the <title> tag (which could be accomplished with regexes) with no real-world examples of how to use the library. So, a good resource or example code for one of the existing, established libraries would also be good.

Comment: As most html parsers give you a tree, you're probably going to have more luck with something like XQuery/XPath or XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple code for transforming a table into a list of tuples using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) looks like this:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String html = 
            "<html><head/><body>" +
                "<table id=\"example\">" +
                    "<tr><td>John</td><td>Doe</td></tr>" +
                    "<tr><td>Michael</td><td>Smith</td>" +
                "</table>" +
            "</body></html>";

        final List<Tuple> tuples = parse (html, "example");
                    //... Here the table is parsed
    }

    private static final List<Tuple> parse(final String html, final String tableId) {
        final List<Tuple> tuples = new LinkedList<Tuple> ();

        final Element table = Jsoup.parse (html).getElementById(tableId);
        final Elements rows = table.getElementsByTag("tr");
        for (final Element row : rows) {
            final Elements children = row.children();
            final int childCount = children.size(); 
            final Tuple tuple = new Tuple (childCount);
            for (final Element child : children) {
                tuple.addColumn (child.text ());
            }
        }

        return tuples;
    }
}

public final class Tuple {
    private final String[] columns;

    private int cursor;

    public Tuple (final int size) {
        columns = new String[size];
        cursor = 0;
    }

    public String getColumn (final int no) {
        return columns[no];
    }

    public void addColumn(final String value) {
        columns[cursor++] = value;
    }
}
```

From this on you can e.g. create an in-memory table with [H2](http://www.h2database.com) and use a regular SQL.